# What's it called when a post 'brings' in multimedia content from another site, like YouTube or Flickr?

Tags: website-design, terminology

I was just curious if there was a term? Is this a onebox? It seems like we have to explain it when there should be a term.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is simply called embedded content.

Comment: My thought too @Joshua! +1

Comment: That's exactly what it's called. In fact, Google uses that exact term on YouTube as one of the share options.

Comment: thx,makes sense. we are using some ruby code called onebox which is why I hear that sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for technical term, that's called an iFrame. They allow you to make requests and display content from content external to your website.

Comment: Written as `iframe`, as iFrame is a video format by Apple.

Comment: It's not always an iframe though.  It's usually an embedded object of some sort.